# Disable touches on a specific layer?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a main scene that is adding many layers to it with , like :

```
[self addChild:layer1];
[self addChild:layer2];
```

..

where `layer1/2` are pointers to other layers in other classes .

I need at some point , to disable the touches only on layer 2, from the main scene, or from layer2 itself .

How would i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
layer2.isTouchEnabled = NO;
```

and from within your layer2 class (i am guessing you are extending CCLayer here) :

```
self.isTouchEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: thanks, but why do i have to set it on layer2 also? is there a way that a parent can control his children's directly ?

Comment: AFAIK you dont have to set it in the layer2 object. Setting it from the parent should be enough. I just put both possibilities to answer fully your question ... which asked for both cases.